# Android LocationListener return null value

Tags: java, android, gps, location, illegalargumentexception

*Main Java File*:

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    TextView tv;
    TextView tv2;
    TextView tv3;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    static final String tag="********MAIN********";
    LocationManager lm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i(tag,"Location Changed Method Called");
        String lat= String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        String log= String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
        tv.setText(lat+ " " + log);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
}
```

*Manifest File:*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="p2p.boysjoys.com.alpha" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

*Error Log:*

> 05-21 18:51:53.970  22842-22842/p2p.boysjoys.com.alpha E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {p2p.boysjoys.com.alpha/p2p.boysjoys.com.alpha.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: listener==null
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2624)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: listener==null
> at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:510)
> at p2p.boysjoys.com.alpha.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:38)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1184)
> at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5082)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2586)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2624)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I m trying to get `location` *as soon as app opens* and it will set to `TextView`, but i get an error on `line no.38` as pointed out to `LogCat`

That line is:

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
```

I tried both `gps` and `network` on `phone` and also on `emulator` but it still giving same error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: listener==null`

Comment: your activity is implementing the LocationListener interface. use this instead of locationListener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
```

with this:

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,this);
```

Your class already implements `LocationListener`. Just use it.
(however, in your code you try to use `locationListener` without initialize it)

Comment: thankyou very much to all it worked and one more mistake i was making that i m setting text without referring to textview in activitymain.xml

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
```

use:

```
 lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,this);
```